# pandas not works for django?

Tags: pandas, apache, centos7, django-2.1

I saw the first rocket.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world.")
```

'Hello, world.' it's ok!
also 'python manage.py migrate' ok.
But when I import pandas...
(import only and no use.)

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import pandas as pd

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world.")
```

Browser thinks forever.
How can I fix this issue?

my environment
OS: CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 (Core)
Pandas: 0.19.2
Apache: 2.4.6 (CentOS)
Django: 2.1
Browser: Google Chrome 76.0.3809.132

```
# python --version
  Python 3.6.0 :: Anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit)
```

simply, Anaconda is older?
Please let me know if there is any missing information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Progress after that. Tried "Panda" update.

`#Conda installs panda`

I was able to clear the browser thinking during the import error.
I will re-install Newest Anaconda.

```
(_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (2006, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)") (Background on this error at: sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

Currently, if you don't use django, you can execute SQL from py file to MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

The situation has improved. It hasn't been resolved yet, but the error has changed this morning. I will challenge again when the work is over.

Answer (score 0):

Settled! I think anaconda was old. Speaking of which, it took about two years to build a VPS, and anaconda was the version at that time.